# Evaluating $\int_{p \in B(0,1)} ||p||$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Today I was studying multivariable calculus and, just out of curiosity, I found myself trying evaluating the following integral:

> Let $p \in \mathbb R^n$ and let $||\cdot ||$ denote the usual norm in $\mathbb R^n$. Let $B(0,1)$ denote the open ball centered at the origin with radius $1$: $$\int_{p \in B(0,1)} ||p||$$

I confess I have no Idea how to even start this. Using the following formula for the "volume" of an $n$ dimensional sphere of radius $R$:

$$V_n(R)=\frac{\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2 + 1)} R^n$$ I think that it makes sense that:

$$0\leq \int_{p \in B(0,1)} ||p||\leq V_n(1)= \frac{\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2 + 1)}$$

I just did a quick google search and I found out about the existence of hyperspherical coordinates. Maybe This could help?

Is this possible to evaluate? How can this be done?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try polar coordinates?

Comment: This is in $\mathbb R^n$, wdym by polar coordinates? @ArcticChar

Comment: Spherical coordinates then.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using spherical coordinates:
$$\int_{p \in B(0,1)}\|p\|d\lambda(p) = \int_{\theta \in \delta B(0,1)}\int_0^1r r^{n-1} dr d\sigma(\theta) = \frac{1}{n+1}\int_{\theta \in \delta B(0,1)}d\sigma(\theta)$$

Perhaps we don't know how to evaluate that integral, but we know $V_n(1)$, so let's also find a formula for it in terms of spherical coordinates:
$$V_n(1) = \int_{p \in B(0,1)} d\lambda(p) = \int_{\theta \in \delta B(0,1)}\int_0^1 r^{n-1} drd\sigma(\theta) = \frac{1}{n} \int_{\theta \in \delta B(0,1)} d\sigma(\theta)$$

It follows that
$$\int_{p\in B(0,1)} \|p\| d\lambda(p) = \frac{n}{n+1}V_n(1)$$

Answer (score 1):

This is a good use for the divergence theorem, because your function $f(p) = \|p\|$ happens to be the divergence of a simple vector field. Let $F : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be the vector field given by

$$ F(x) = \|x\| \, x $$

(Visually, $F(x)$ is the vector in the direction of $x$ with magnitude $\|x\|^2$.)

Then given the vector $x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$,

$$ F(x) = \sqrt{x_1^2 + \cdots + x_n^2} \, \big(x_1, \ldots, x_n\big) $$
$$ F_k(x) = x_k \sqrt{x_1^2 + \cdots + x_n^2} $$
$$ \frac{\partial F_k(x)}{\partial x_k} = \sqrt{x_1^2 + \cdots + x_n^2} + \frac{x_k^2}{\sqrt{x_1^2 + \cdots + x_n^2}}$$
$$ \nabla \cdot F(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n \left[ \sqrt{x_1^2 + \cdots + x_n^2} + \frac{x_k^2}{\sqrt{x_1^2 + \cdots + x_n^2}} \right] $$
$$ \nabla \cdot F(x) = n \sqrt{x_1^2 + \cdots + x_n^2} + \frac{x_1^2 + \cdots + x_n^2}{\sqrt{x_1^2 + \cdots + x_n^2}} $$
$$ \nabla \cdot F(x) = (n+1) \|x\| $$

Integration is simplest to define on closed sets, if you're okay with taking the closed unit ball instead of the open unit ball. Or if we're using Lebesgue integration, the integral is the same as long as the function is bounded and the domain's boundary has Lebesgue measure zero. So by the divergence theorem, integral of divergence equals integral of outward field flux through the boundary surface:

$$ \int_{B(0,1)} \|x\|\, dx = \frac{1}{n+1} \int_{B(0,1)} \nabla \cdot F(x) \, dx = \frac{1}{n+1} \int_{S^{n-1}} F(x) \cdot \frac{x}{\|x\|} \, d\sigma $$

where $S^{n-1} = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \|x\|=1 \}$ is the unit sphere. But $F(x) \cdot x = \|x\|^3$, and since we're evaluating on surface $x \in S^{n-1}$, we have $\|x\|=1$, so this becomes just

$$ \int_{B(0,1)} \|x\|\, dx = \frac{1}{n+1} \int_{S^{n-1}} d\sigma = \frac{\mathop{\mathrm{vol}} S^{n-1}}{n+1} $$

Substituting the known form for the volume of the unit $(n-1)$-sphere,

$$ \int_{B(0,1)} \|x\|\, dx = \frac{2 \pi^{n/2}}{(n+1) \Gamma\!\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)} $$

Comment: Uau, really likes your answer, thanks